# Mounting Windows 8.1 partition in fstab fails even when FastBoot is turned off

Tags: partition, windows, automounting, hibernate

I'm using Arch Linux, and with this in my fstab for mounting my Windows partition:

```
/dev/sda2    /media/windows  ntfs-3g  josh,exec  0 0
```

it panics and goes into emergency mode on boot. I turned off FastBoot, as several articles have suggested, but while Windows doesn't go into hibernation, it still seems to be locking the NTFS partition.

I like to have Linux use files on my Windows partition (for example, symlinking ~/Pictures to /media/windows/Users/Josh/Pictures) so I don't have to reinvent the wheel, so to speak.

How can I get Windows to unlock its partition when it shuts down?

Comment: Try `mount -a` too see if that gives any error before rebooting.

Comment: I think problem is with `exec` tag. Instead of `josh,exec`, try `defaults`.

Comment: I unmounted it, set the options to defaults, and it still gave this error:


Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.

Comment: Maybe, fast boot isn't completely turned off. I would recommend turning off hibernation completely. In Windows, open `cmd` as administrator and type following: `powercfg /h off`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after running `powercfg /h` off it mounts correctly now

Comment: Every reply up to that point had been a comment as opposed to an answer, so after figuring it out, I just created an answer to close it.

Comment: @rzaaeeff actually it is. Answers shouldn't be posted as comments and, if they are, copying them into an answer is [completely acceptable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157912/203101). It would have been better if Josh had expanded this into a proper answer, explaining how he ran the command and what it does. This is not a good answer since it doesn't provide an explanation. That it was copied from a comment is not a problem, however, that's why answers shouldn't be posted as comments.